# String Concatenation issue in Spark SQL when using rtrim()

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing a peculiar or unknown concatenation problem during PySpark SQL query

```py
spark.sql("select *,rtrim(IncomeCat)+' '+IncomeCatDesc as trimcat from Dim_CMIncomeCat_handled").show()
```

In this query both IncomeCat and IncomeCatDesc fields hold String type value so logically i thought it would concatenate but i get resultant field null

[image]

where the achievable result will be '14100abcd' where 14100 is IncomeCat part and abcd is IncomeCatdesc part . i have tried explicit casting as well on IncomeCat field

```py
spark.sql("select *,cast(rtrim(IncomeCat) as string)+' '+IncomeCatDesc as IncomeCatAndDesc from Dim_CMIncomeCat_handled").show()
```

but I am getting same result. so  am i something missing here. kindly help me to solve this

Comment: point to be noted that rtrim(IncomCat)  is working but when i concatenate with IncomeCatDesc value it is giving null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark doesn't override `+` operator for strings and as a result query you use doesn't express concatenation. If you take a look at the basic example you'll see what is going on:

```py
spark.sql("SELECT 'a' + 'b'").explain()
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [null AS (CAST(a AS DOUBLE) + CAST(b AS DOUBLE))#48]
+- Scan OneRowRelation[]
```

Both arguments are assumed to be numeric and in general case the result will be undefined. Of course it will work for strings that can be casted to numerics:

```py
spark.sql("SELECT '1' + '2'").show()
```

```
+---------------------------------------+
|(CAST(1 AS DOUBLE) + CAST(2 AS DOUBLE))|
+---------------------------------------+
|                                    3.0|
+---------------------------------------+
```

To concatenate strings you can use `concat`:

```py
spark.sql("SELECT CONCAT('a', 'b')").show()
```

```
+------------+
|concat(a, b)|
+------------+
|          ab|
+------------+
```

or `concat_ws`:

```
spark.sql("SELECT CONCAT_WS('*', 'a', 'b')").show()
```

```
+------------------+
|concat_ws(*, a, b)|
+------------------+
|               a*b|
+------------------+
```